Current varies with constant firing time in an SCR
Please bear with me as I am not a power electronics guy.
I have a circuit in a battery charger that triggers SCRs, attached here. I am generating the fire pulse from a microcontroller at a constant timing measured with the help of a zero crossing detector. Everything is shown perfectly on the oscilloscope. My goal is to maintain a constant charging current.
To maintain the current, I have taken feedback using an INA225EVM as shown in image attached (Shunt = 1 mOhm, INA225 gain set to 200.) The ammeter shows 2 amperes drawn by the battery and 2mV appears at the input of INA, but Vout does not follow Vin. To test the INA225EVM I applied pure DC 2 ampere and Vout gives the correct value. Why does i not work with rectified DC?

SCR pulse generation:

 Please help someone.

Current measurement circuit:



I had the same problem, as the battery is charging with pulses, the current does, do you have some type of filter in your code? Because if you read the signal in any time of the pulse, it could be 0 Amps ( volts in INA225EVM output ). You need to make some type of average code. Then for making constant current, the best way I´m thinking is a PID, or something less sophisticated. Hope it helps!

There are many things that affect the charging current of a battery, and the applied voltage is only one of them. The resistance of the battery itself depends on things like its state of charge, its temperature, etc. You can't assume that constant voltage will result in constant current. You'll need some sort of feedback loop if you really want to regulate the current.

Hi, Thank you for your suggestion, for feedback I added INA225EVM and applied bridge rectified AC to IN+ and IN- terminals. The output of the amplifier does not follow the input. When I test INA225EVM with independent DC applied at sense input, it gives correct output. Something I need to change when I apply rectified AC on sense input?

Without a complete diagram of your setup, it's impossible to say. Please add these details to your question.

I have updated the question with details but haven't heard back yet. Anyone please?

Not enough detail. You said, "The output of the amplifier does not follow the input." But you neglected to tell us what you actually saw. You added a diagram, but it's missing important details such as how you're powering the INA225.
